# Why do I receive a message twice asking me if I want to pair with LESC Just Works?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on an on-board device which will have to communicate in Bluetooth with a smartphone. I would like the communication to be secure using LESC (LE Secure Connection) using the "Just Works" pairing method.

The problem I see is that when I connect, the smartphone asks me 2 times if I want to perform the pairing: I only have this problem in recent versions of Android.

My question is therefore to know if it is an Android bug or if the problem comes from my code?

Here are the tests I performed:

- If I connect with a Samsung S7 (Android 8), the smartphone asks me only once if I want to pair
- If I connect with a device that is in Android 10, the smartphone asks me twice if I want to pair
- If I connect with a device that is in Android 11 (Samsung S10), the smartphone asks me twice if I want to pair I don't have this problem
- if I connect with an IOS (the smartphone asks me only once if I want to pair)

If I connect and accept the first message asking me if I want to pair, I see that the smartphone sends this:
[image]
And if I accept the second message asking me if I want to pair:
[image]

Why does it perform pairing in 2 times when it does it well in one time with Android 8?

Also, I noticed that if I press "cancel" when I get the second message, I get from the smartphone: "Sent Pairing Failed: Numeric Comparison Failed".
However, I have configured my device so that it sends in its pairing response: No Input / No Output (IO Capability), no OOB, Secure Connection activate, no bonding. So it looks like the smartphone uses "numeric comparison" when it should use "just works" right?

Here is my pairing response:
[image]

Thank you